# Where to place the files that can be downloaded by the user

Tags: html, download, anchor

I was working on a project and came across a problem

I wanted to give the user a file to download so I wrote this anchor tag

```
<a href="Sample.xls">Download here</a>
```

the problem is when i click on this link the browser is showing a 404 error

I would have thought my mechanism was wrong except that when I link it to a html file(present in the same directory) it is working fine.

```
<a href="select.html">Download here</a>
```

This seems to be working fine

Is the link not working because the browser cannot handle the excel file and can handle html files? If yes, how can i resolve the issue?

**P.S.** I'm using tomcat to publish the site and all the resource files are in the root directory of the web application

Answer (score 1):

Follow below link. It has answer.

To download excel file you should mention content

In link button On click event handler add this code :

```
string path = @getpathfromappconfig + "\\" + FileName + ".xlsx";
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
string Outgoingfile = FileName + ".xlsx"; 
if (file.Exists)
{ 
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);

}
else
{
    Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: I tried this code with <a href="" onclick="return download()">download</a>.. Still the html file is opening.. download is the function in which i wrote the above code..

Comment: http protocol only knows html. so its returning html file without any modifications.. for other type of files you need to mention content type and all code as is answered. Which technonlogy you are using Asp.Net WebForm or MVC